# How do I tell Wolfram Alpha that I want it to compute the terms of an integer sequence?

Tags: wolframalpha

I want to compute a list of the terms of the sequence

```
(14747-40*n)/(2621440*(41-n)), n from 1 to 40
```

I tried entering the above in Wolfram Alpha, and it plots me a graph of the function. This isn't what I want. I've tried variations on this command, as well as guessing at various keywords to stick before it, and I either get back the same thing, or something unhelpful.

The [help page on sequences](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sequence) suggests various things you might do with sequences, but doesn't say how to do something simple like this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
Table[(14747-40*n)/(2621440*(41-n)) n, {n, 1, 40}]
```

Clicking on "approximate form" then on "copy plaintext" gives the following:

> {0.000140257, 0.000286924, 0.000440507, 0.000601567, 0.000770728,
>   0.000948683, 0.00113621, 0.00133417, 0.00154356, 0.00176547,
>   0.00200115, 0.00225204, 0.00251976, 0.00280618, 0.00311345,
>   0.00344409, 0.00380101, 0.00418764, 0.00460803, 0.00506701,
>   0.00557035, 0.00612508, 0.00673974, 0.00742493, 0.00819385,
>   0.00906326, 0.0100547, 0.0111963, 0.0125257, 0.0140939, 0.0159728,
>   0.0182658, 0.0211282, 0.0248041, 0.0297003, 0.0365488, 0.0468139,
>   0.0639122, 0.0980936, 0.200607}